# VBA Repeat Character Or Number in Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to repeat two characters(Y,N) 2^a number of times infinitely along a column in excel. So in the first column each character will repeat 2^0 = 1 and look like this:

```
Y
N
Y
N
```

The second column repeats infinitely 2^1 =2 times

```
Y
Y
N
N
Y
Y
N
N
```

and so on- I need to do this for 24 columns! Is there a simple way to do this? I think it may have to use an array formula...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(MOD(TRUNC((ROW()-1)/2^(COLUMN()-1)),2)=0,"Y","N")
```

Answer (score 3):

In A1

```
=IF(MOD(TRUNC((ROW()-1)/COLUMN()),2)=0,"Y","N")
```

fill down and right as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using the `Substitute` and `Repeat` functions nested together.

For example, suppose you had your original string in cell `A1` (A1 = "YN"), 
then in A2 moving down you have your number of times to replace (A2 = 2^0, A3 = 2^1, A4 = 2^2, ... ), your formula could look as follows:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"N",REPT("N",$A2)),"Y",REPT("Y",$A2))
```

And then you can just drag that formula down

Hope that makes sense

Comment: I should have been more specific, sorry! Each cell has only one character, and I need to drag it down the column. So the first column looks like this:

Y
N
Y
N

and the second column looks like this 

Y
Y
N
N

and so on, infinitely down the column. This process goes on for 24 columns...

Comment: FASTEST solution, Replace A1 with "Y N" (put a space in between) change the formula to: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"N",REPT(" N",$A2)),"Y",REPT(" Y",$A2))` Once you drag it down copy and paste special > values, then do `Data` > `Text To Columns` use a space delimiter and choose `Treat consecutive delimiters as one` ... That should get you there.... Although it could just as easily be done in a VBA for loop, but I already had the cool formula working :p

Comment: Wait... I'm reading your comment again... I think I'm still missing what it is you're trying to do....

Comment: Okay, column A looks like this: Y N Y N Y N and repeats this pattern all the way down, column B looks like this: Y Y N N Y Y N N and repeats that pattern all the way to the bottom, column C looks like: Y Y Y Y N N N N and again repeats. If I only had to do this for 5 columns I'd just drag the pattern manually but I need to do it for 24 columns.

Comment: How many times do you have "YN" repeated? For example is it always 3 repetitions of "YN", just increasing amounts of "Y"s and "N"s? - Meaning all of column A would be "YNYNYN" and all of column B would be "YYNNYYNNYYNN", etc??

Comment: Assuming that's what you want - this formula should do the trick `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("YNYNYN","N",REPT("N",2^(COLUMN()-1))),"Y",REPT("Y",2^(COLUMN()-1)))` - I would suggest just doing this on the first row, then copying / pasting special values for the rest of the sheet since it would be a lot of formulas to evaluate otherwise....